# How to combine parts of data of 2 tables?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

```
t1

id   |   name   |   content
-----------------------------------------
1    |  first   |   the first one
2    |  second  |   the second one


t2

id   |  ref_ID  |   description
-----------------------------------------
1    |    2     |   server
```

and I want to get **all colums of the first table and the "description" column of the second where t2.ref_ID = t1.id**.

So the result should look like this

```
id   |   name   |      content     |   description
-----------------------------------------------------
1    |  first   | the first one    | 
2    |  second  | the second one   |  server
```

**If there is no entry in the second table, "description" should be empty.**

How can I do this? I tried join but that wasn't right I guess.

Cheers

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.  This is pretty basic SQL.

Comment: What database engine are you working on?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the following:

```
   select t1.*, t2.description from table1 t1 left table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.ref_id;
```

Keep in mind that you should replace `table1` and `table2` with the actual names of your tables.

Comment: It might be helpfull to explain how the left join works. Also your answer only works with some database engines.

Comment: That statement returns every row that has an entry in table 2. If there is no entry in table 2 that matches t2.ref_ID = t1.id, "description" should be empty but all table 1 data need be in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I created the same table structure in Oracle with similar names and with same data.

```
SELECT
 t1.id, t1.cl_name, t1.cl_content, t2.cl_desc
FROM
 tbl_a t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_b t2 
ON t1.id = t2.ref_id;
```

**RESULT:**

[image]